# HTML 5 Audio with Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, playlist

I've started to use the script from the jsfiddle link, http://jsfiddle.net/WsXX3/33/ for an HTML5 audio player with a playlist. The HTML and CSS parts were no problem to place/import. However I'm finding it difficult getting the javascript to run. The audio player only plays the file placed in the audio tag. When I click on one song from the playlist it takes me to another page (black background) where the audio file plays. My question is do I import this script or should I place it in the head of the html file. Also, what would be the right tags to run that following script (shown below):

```
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .10;
    audio[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });enter code here
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var audio;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;

init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    audio = $('audio');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length; // - 1;
    audio[0].volume = .5;
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, audio[0]);
    });
    audio[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),audio[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        audio[0].load();
        audio[0].play();
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put init(); at the bottom of your code. You're calling init before the function is created.

Comment: I placed init(); at the bottom of my code and nothing changed.